# Swift- how to position an item when working with a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

So I currently have a UIScrollView that allows the user to scroll vertically down the page. I also have a UIBarButton that when clicked creates a button in the center of the page, however, because of the UIScrollView I can't tell the button a simple CGRectMake coordinate because the "center" of the screen is dependent on how far the user has scrolled down. I am not using story boards.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the button doesn't need to be inside of the scrollview I would add it to the superview of the scrollview by using it's center

```
theButton.frame = CGRect(x:scrollView.center.x ,y: scrollView.center.y ,width:buttonWidht, height: buttonHeight)
scrollViewSuperView.addSubview(theButton)
```

If it needs to be inside the scrollview you need to calculate the current y center. You can do this by adding the height of the scrollView to the current scrollOffset and divide it by 2

```
let currYCenter = (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) / 2
theButton.frame = CGRect(x:scrollView.center.x ,y: currYCenter ,width:buttonWidht, height: buttonHeight)
scrollView.addSubview(theButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you should use `contentOffset`; this property of `UIScrollView` returns how much the user has scrolled down / right.

Comment: He is right, but you will have to get the Screen Size UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds() to get the screen dimensions and do the math yourself with the contentOffset. @TimMcneal

Comment: Correct. but it is `bounds`, not `bounds()`.